# Chess challenge #1: Mate in one

Tags: checkmate, problems

This is the first of a series of challenges I'll be posting regularly. In this case it is just a *simple* mate in one. This is the position:

```
 [Title "White to mate in one"]
 [FEN "1Bb3BN/R2Pk1pr/1Q5B/4q2R/2bN/4Q1BK/1p/1bq1R1rb w - - 0 1"]
```

White plays and gives mate. It seems very easy but there are a lot of pieces in the board. I'll be increasing or reducing the level of the challenges based on the answers.

Comment: Hi @Adolfo! Good idea for a series of posts (reminds me of Puzzling.SE). If you are posting a problem from a specific place, can you include the source please? If not, well done on composing an engaging problem!

Comment: @Bad_Bishop Thanks, I was thinking about something similar. I don't know any "official" source for this one, a member of my chess club showed it to me a few weeks ago, but I don't know where she found it. I'll add the source from now on.

Comment: Thanks for that. I am not a lawyer, but the discussion of copyrighting in chess has come up before (e.g. http://www.chess.com/forum/view/general/who-owns-my-games-and-puzzles). I just wouldn't want you to risk getting in hot water for making a good post.

Comment: This checkmate is mentioned in a Ben Finegold video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0saFg21rbY8

Comment: Ual, Black has FOUR light-bishops o.O

Comment: I did not check all pieces, but it seems to me that Blacks Rh7 and Pg7 can be removed without changing the solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that

> Qa3

is mate in one. It is indeed harder than it looks at first sight, because there are so many pins.

Answer (score 2):

Nice puzzle, this took me a few minutes.

> The answer is 1.Qa3#.

Answer (score 1):

Moving

> D7 to D8

ending up with 3 Queens

Comment: d7-d8Q would be invalid - the pawn is pinned against the king by the bishop on c8.

Comment: @A.A. If we overlook d8 being illegal, a queen on d8 would attack the king in addition to the rook on a7, and Bb7 would block only one of these attacks. I don’t understand your comment.

Answer (score 0):

The only escape sqare that isn't currently covered by White is f8.
1. Ng6 is the only move which gives check, while also defending f8, without also opening up another escape square.
1. Qc5 comes close, but it allows 1… Kd8.

Comment: 1… Bxg6. Nevermind. 